# Flutter: How to save user's input from a ListView.builder of TextFields

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to **save user's input** from a *ListView.builder* of *TextFields* in a list of objects **when he presses a button**. [Screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmAlE.png)

I would like that when the user presses the button save, all the hello words were storaged as the text property of my object.

That is my code:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ListData listData = Provider.of<ListData>(context, listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add Textfields'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            color: Colors.red,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('Save'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
            child: TextFieldBuilder(),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              listData.addTextField();
            },
            child: Text(
              'Add',
              style: TextStyle(
                letterSpacing: 4,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Builderclass:

```
class TextFieldBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ListData>(
      builder: (context, listData, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: listData.textFieldList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return TextFieldWidget(index: index);
          },
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

TextFieldWidget:

```
class TextFieldWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  TextFieldWidget({this.index});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    );
  }
}
```

And the **list of objects**:

```
class TextFieldData {
  String text;

  TextFieldData({this.text});
}

class ListData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<TextFieldData> textFieldList = [];

  void addTextField() {
    textFieldList.add(TextFieldData());
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution:

First creating a `List<TextEditingController>` and after a **for loop** in the 'Save' button. Here is the code:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ListData listData = Provider.of<ListData>(context, listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add Textfields'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            color: Colors.red,
            onPressed: () { 
              for (int i = 0; i < listData.textFieldList.length; i++) {
                listData.textFieldList[i].text = listData.controllers[i].text;      // for loop
              }
            },
            child: Text('Save'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
            child: TextFieldBuilder(),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              listData.addTextField();
            },
            child: Text(
              'Add',
              style: TextStyle(
                letterSpacing: 4,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Builder class:

```
class TextFieldBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ListData>(
      builder: (context, listData, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: listData.textFieldList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            //adds a controller to the controller list
            listData.controllers.add(new TextEditingController());    

            //added the controller to the widget
            return TextFieldWidget(controller: listData.controllers[index],);
          },
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

TextFieldWidget:

```
//set the controller inside the widget
class TextFieldWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;

  TextFieldWidget({this.controller});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      controller: controller,
    );
  }
}
```

And the **list of objects and TextEditingControllers**:

```
class TextFieldData {
  String text;

  TextFieldData({this.text});
}

class ListData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<TextFieldData> textFieldList = [];
  List<TextEditingController> controllers = new List();    //list of controllers

  void addTextField() {
    textFieldList.add(TextFieldData());
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```